# Programs can't find their databases after restoring from backup

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I replaced my D drive due to a crash. I had a back up of D, so after replacing the D drive I copied most of the content back to same directory structure. But now programs that had databases stored on the D drive say they cannot find the D drive.

Comment: What do you mean you had a backup of the HDD? As an image? How did you restore the other "content"? Without additional information for *what you did*, it will be very difficult to diagnose troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible NTFS permissions are not the same as before. Or, it may be more dependent on the specific applications that need their data. What are some of the specific programs?

You did say "most of the content." It's possible some of the content that was needed wasn't restored.

Also, ensure that the new drive did indeed appear as `D:\`. If it's not the letter you want, you can run `compmgmt.msc` on Windows 7 (I'm running Professional. It may not be available in Win 7 Home Premium) and navigate to `Storage\Disk Management`. You can right-click the volume you wish to change drive letter:

[image: Change drive letter]
You can select `Change Drive Letter and Paths` and make sure it's D:.

Comment: This was the answer. after replacing D drive which was a 750 gig conventional drive we installed a 256 gig ssd. Then added programs and databases back to the original directory structure.Then we added dual boot capability for Ubuntu 14.4- This wiped the drive letter!